# Poincare map of this system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-theory

Let $$x'=1+y-x^2-y^2$$
$$y'=1-x-x^2-y^2$$

> How do I use the Poincare map to show that this has a not asymptotically stable solution?

What I did:
I transformed the system to polar coordinates
$$r'=(\cos\theta+\sin\theta)(1-r^2)$$
$$\theta'=(\cos\theta-\sin\theta)(1/r-r)-1$$
which has a periodic solution $(r,\theta)=(1,-t)$ or $f(t)=(x,y)=(\cos(t),-\sin(t))$.
How do I find the Poincare map? And how do I show that $f(t)$ is not aymptotically stable?

Edit:
The original question gives the system as above and asks for an explicit periodic solution $f(t)$ (which I'm sure is the one I found above).

> Show that $f(t)$ is stable (but not asymptotically stable). What can you say about the Poincare map?

Comment: Do you really need to study that using Poincare map? Can you attach the text of original problem if it isn't the same (just to make sure that your question [is not of this kind](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378))?

Comment: @Evgeny See edit, I cannot attach the original text, but I transcribed it

Comment: There is a formula for a first term of Poincaré map: it equals $\exp{\left (\frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{0}^{T} \left ( P'_x(x(t), y(t)) + Q'_y (x(t), y(t)) \right ) \, dt \right )}$. I don't know whether you can use it or not. If you want to stay in polar coordinates, Poincaré map is usually computed by setting $\theta = 0$ as a transversal and by studying equation for $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = f(r, \theta)$. If you somehow can analyze it, then the Poincaré map is just a $r_{n+1} - r_{n} = \int\limits_{0}^{2\pi} f(\gamma(\theta), \theta)\, d\theta$, where $\gamma(\theta)$ is a solution of ...

Comment: ... Cauchy problem $\gamma(0) = r_n$ for $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = f(r, \theta)$.

Comment: I also must correct myself: the integral $\exp{\left (\frac{1}{T} \int\limits_{0}^{T} \left ( P'_x(x(t), y(t)) + Q'_y (x(t), y(t)) \right ) \, dt \right )}$ must be computed along the periodic solution $(x(t), y(t))$ which is of a period $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Making the transformation

$$
x = u+v\\
y = u-v
$$

the dynamical system becomes

$$
\cases{
u'=1-v-2(u^2+v^2)\\
v'=u
}
$$

now following with

$$
\frac{du}{dv} = \frac{1-v-2(u^2+v^2)}{u}
$$

and integrating we get

$$
u(v) = \pm\frac{\sqrt{1-2v^2+\left(2u_0^2-1\right)e^{-4v}}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Follows a plot shoving the level paths for some values for $u(0) = u_0$. The system behaves as a conservative system with centers for $|u_0| < \sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{1}{e^4}\right)}$

[image]

Attached a MATHEMATICA script which builds the Poincaré map for $u(t),v(t)$ for the initial conditions $(u(0) = 0.7107, v(0)=0)$ in the plane $(v ,u)$

```
data = Block[{}, 
Reap[NDSolve[{Derivative[1][x][t] == 
    1 - 2 x[t]^2 - y[t] - 2 y[t]^2, Derivative[1][y][t] == x[t], 
   x[0] == 0.7107, y[0] == 0, 
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, 2 \[Pi]] == 0, Sow[{y[t], x[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 100000}, MaxSteps -> \[Infinity]]]][[-1, 1]];
ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, All}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.0025]]
```

[image]

[image]